# Incorporate braintree in Salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I am trying to implement braintree in LWC , everything looks correct but not able to see the cmp on UI. below are the steps.

1. Created Static resource as braintree and uploaded braintree JS library.
2. Below is my LWC code .

HTML;

```
<template>
<div lwc:dom="manual" id="dropin-container"></div>
<button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import braintreejs from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/braintree";

export default class Resources extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track resources = [];
    @track showResources = false;


    loaded = false;
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('I am here in the Debug message');
        if (this.loaded) {
            return;
        }
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, braintreejs + "/dropin.min.js"),
            loadScript(this, braintreejs + "/jquery-3.2.1.min.js")
        ]).then(() => {
            this.loaded = true;
            var button = this.template.querySelector('button');
            var div = this.template.querySelector('div');
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(div.id));
            braintree.dropin.create({
                authorization: 'CLIENT_TOKEN',
                container: '#' + div.id
            }, function (createErr, instance) {
                button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    console.log('inside');
                    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
                        // Submit payload.nonce to your server
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Error: Component is not appearing on the screen and we are not getting any error in console.

Answer (score 3):

Your template querySelector should ideally be referencing a class, so, you should try and use a class instead of an id for your container.

`<div lwc:dom="manual" class="dropin-container"></div>`

and adjust your querySelector

`this.template.querySelector('.dropin-container')`

Additionally, you might want to chec for the element's height, you can verify that by using your browsers developer tools. Sometimes, the element will be inserted, but with a height of 0px, which may result in you seeing a "blank" or empty container.

Comment: Its working , but when i am clicking on the button nothing happening, can someone help me out for this

Comment: the same applies for your button, you need to reference a class name.